# Codeigniter says "Unable to load the requested file" to my controller's method

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, routes

After I have uploaded last version of application to the server, I have found the following problem:

After my admin controller redirects unauthorized user to *admin/login* page(

```
redirect('admin/login','refresh');
```

), codeigniter returns an error:

*Unable to load the requested file: admin/login.php*

**My local login page works well.**

Rewrites for virtual hosts are the same, and *.htaccess* files are the same. Codeigniter routes are not used, just a default controller, and it is also the same.

Have I missed something?

Below goes my login function of admin controller:

```
public function login()
{
    $form_created = $this->_admin_login_form();

    if ($form_created){
        return true;
    }

    $password = $this->input->post('pwd');
    if (! $this->_check_admin_pwd($password)) {
        error_log('ERROR');
        exit;
    }

    $this->_cookie_admin_login();
    error_log('SUCCESS');
    redirect('admin/news','refresh');
}
```

Comment: where do you use `redirect('admin/login','refresh');` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not the request to controller's method, but to the view file.

Answer (score -2):

you can only load my_view.php from controller.
may be you can have two files with the same name and a different extension that is such as my_view.html and my_view.php!